# How to launch android plugin app within nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to launch Android app that I've packed inside a plugin for nativescript

I followed [this](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/plugins-and-jars) tutorial and I imported everything correctly, but I can't find anywhere how could I launch the android app in the way that I have it(i.e. launch onCreate() or even displayMessage()).

Here is how my main activity looks like

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

        //etc..
    }

    private void displayMessage(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do things
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

How do I show(or launch) my android app content from within nativescript in that case? What steps am I missing? I'm very new ns..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just start the MainActivity via an intent.

Here is the pseudocode.

```
const intent = new android.content.Intent(application.android.context, your.package.name.MainActivity.class);
application.android.foregroundActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thank you so much! It's now showed me that I'm missing DemoActivity in AndroidManifest.xml so I added it in App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifext.xml, but then I got an error `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "your.package.name.R$layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.nativescript.TnsApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.TnsApp-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/org.nativescript.TnsApp-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]`   Is it because I didn't properly created jars?

Comment: Could be, the activity class should be public, so it could accessed from JS runtime.

Comment: the activity class is declared as public indeed, I think that the program crashes on the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);`. Does it mean that I will have to put into plugin libs folder all android jar files(android.arch, com.android.support etc.)?  But I don't think it should work like that..

Comment: Your layouts will be compiled as part of JAR, if may crash only when it doesn't find the layouts.

Comment: So does this ClassNotFoundException mean that the layouts weren't properly exported to jar?

Comment: I didn't say that. You had mentioned it crashes on the specific line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);`, may be the layout was not found or something. But if you get `ClassNotFoundException` in the log, then it's different, your class is not visible. If you using plugin, make sure you run a clean build. Any updates on the JAR may not auto sync sometimes.

Comment: I did run `Tasks>build>clean` ad then `Tasks>other>createFullJarRelease` on both my android app modules but still same error. Then I put both modules `full.jar` from /build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/release/ into plugins libs folder. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I meant clean build the NativeScript app, assuming this exception was at runtime when you tried to launch the activity from NativeScript Activity.

Comment: ran `tns platform clean`, removed node_modules and platforms dirs, reimported plugin and same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195145/discussion-between-kyrylo-lukeniuk-and-manoj).

Comment: an tns platform clean, removed node_modules and platforms dirs, reimported plugin and same error
It was happening during the runtime. I also did tns build android. If there is something else I could do please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what else could be the issue without debugging the code, but I can confirm there are many plugins launches Activity on a plugin method call.

Comment: there was an issue on my side, I didn't include resources. Had to generate .aar file instead of .jar